# How can I pass data into a bootstrap model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

My basic environment is node.js, [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org), and MongoDB.

I'm generating an SVG with data and coordinates pulled from a DB and using the 'onclick' functionality to call a function which opens a modal window. My end goal is to be able to click on a shape (represents a bench) and have a modal open with the db info for that shape/bench. What I'm having issues with is figuring how to pass data to the modal so it knows which shape/bench I selected and lists the data for that db object. Currently if I open a modal by selecting a bench it lists every variable call I make (this.example) as 'undefined' which is obviously because it's not being passed that data.

Example of how I'm generating the shapes/benches:

```
// Foreach function generates shapes/benches from 'lab' collection in DB.
// bFill variable is generated within this function based on whether this bench is set to active or not.

<rect 
    id="<%= lab.number%>" 
    x="<%= lab.x %>" 
    y="<%= lab.y %>" 
    fill="<%= this.bFill %>" 
    stroke="#000000" 
    stroke-width="0.25" 
    stroke-miterlimit="10" 
    width="<%= lab.w %>" 
    height="<%= lab.h %>" 
    onclick="bench(this.id)" 
    >
```

Example of the function I'm calling:

```
function bench(bNum) {
            $('#myModal').modal("show");
        }
```

I'm still a fairly new to JS, JQuery and Bootstrap, so I'm figuring I'm forgetting something glaring obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want to pass some variable to a javascript function, You should define a function with some arguments. In your case, you can do something like this:

```
function bench(data1, data2, ...) {
       $('#myModal .modal-body').html("data1: " + data1 + " - data2: " + data2); //Or something like this
       $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }


 onclick="bench(this.id, 'Test')"
```

If you see `undefined` error, the problem is `this.id` .

Comment: So I've tried this and it works...sort of. It does pass the variables data1 & data2, but using the method above just injects the function data into modal-body and entirely replaces the content code I had actually written for modal-body. Is there a way I can pass the variables into an object which can be freely referenced within the modal?

Comment: hey @TheMeanWon did you solve the problem? i want to know that too